# $0$-"norm" minimization with least-squares regularization

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, combinatorial-optimization

I have the following optimization problem in $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}$

$$\min_{\mathbf{x}>0} \quad \|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\|_0 + \alpha \|\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}\|_2^2$$

where $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times K}$ are (very) fat matrices ($L<K$) and $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{L\times 1}$. Moreover,

$$\mathbf{A} = \left( \begin{array} {cccccccccccccccccc} \mathbf{1}_1 & \mathbf{0} & \cdots & \mathbf{0}\\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{0} \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots&\vdots \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots & \mathbf{1}_K \\ \end{array} \right)$$

where $\mathbf{1}_k=(1, 1, \dots, 1)$ is a $1 \times m_k$ vector whose elements are $1$.

Comment: And what is $\|x\|_0$?

Comment: zero-norm measuring the number of non-zero elements in $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: $\mathbf{A}=\left( \begin{array} {cccccccccccccccccc}
 \mathbf{1}_1 & \mathbf{0} & \cdots & \mathbf{0}\\
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{0} \\
 \vdots &\vdots  & \ddots&\vdots \\ 
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots & \mathbf{1}_K \\
\end{array} \right)$ and $\mathbf{1}_k=(1, 1, \dots, 1)$ is a $1\times m_k$ vector with all the elements being $1$. $A^T$ is a very tall matrix.

Comment: Since matrix $\bf B$ is very fat, why even use least-squares regularization? Why not append the equality constraint $\bf Bx = c$? To me, this very much looks like a **least-norm** problem in the $0$-"norm".

Comment: Have you looked into compressive sensing literature, specifically lasso problem where 0 norm is replaced by one norm without changing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\ell_0$ optimization is NP-hard in general, even strongly so:

- Dongdong Ge, Xiaoye Jiang, Yinyu Ye, [A Note on the Complexity of $L_p$ Minimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eyyye/lpmin_v14.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: This one probably has good approximation.

Comment: thanks, i will take a look.